# Facebook won't send notifications from messages sent by a user that was transferred from a bot to the facebook page inbox by the Handover Protocol

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I will name my firstborn after whoever answers my question!

My bot uses the Handover Protocol to transfer users from the bot (primary receiver) to the page's inbox (secondary receiver) after they tap on a 'chat with human' button, the problem is that I'm not getting any facebook notifications when the user starts messaging a human (page inbox).

Right now I'm having the bot email me anytime it transfers a user to a human but this fix obviously doesn't scale, ideally I would want facebook to send me notifications on my phone just like it does by default to pages that receive messages and don't have any bots installed.

I know I can see the messages sent to a human by using the 'standby' webhook but those are developer-side server logs, what I want are normal facebook notifications sent to the page owner and the people in the page's Roles so they reply to those messages instead of me (the developer) being the only one being notified through emails I have to send myself.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score -1):

1.You have to go to Your Page--> Settings--> Notifications--> Select this option 
 from Messages- "Get a notification each time your Page receives a message".
2.Download "Facebook Pages Manager" App to get all your page related notification 
  on your phone.